# Play sound asynchronously in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a `while loop` for my cameras(with opencv) to take a photos when something moves. I would like to call a function to play a sound as well. But when I call and play it, it will stop looping for that execution time. I tried `ThreadPoolExecutor` but had no idea how could I blend it with my code, because I'm not passing anything to the function. Just calling it from loop. Btw. I would like to be able to play it multiple times (multiple executions in time of execution) if multiple `something` in code appears from loop

camera script

```
from play_it import alert

while True:
    #do something in cv2
    if "something":
        alert() # Here it slowing the loop
```

and my `play_it` script

```
from playsound import playsound
import concurrent.futures

def alert():
    playsound('ss.mp3')


def PlayIt():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
        exe.map(alert, ???) # not sure what to insert here
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/): `There’s an optional second argument, block, which is set to True by default. Setting it to False makes the function run asynchronously.`. Have you tried `playsound('ss.mp3', block=False)`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried as you said but :`"block=False cannot be used on this platform yet"`

Comment: For what it's worth: `playsound` now appears to support `block=False` on all platforms - Linux support was merged in https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/pull/72. So, it should no longer be necessary to use a thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know what requirements `playsound` has for the thread it runs on, but the simplest and easiest thing to do is probably just to spawn off a thread to play the sound:

```
import threading
def alert():
    threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=('ss.mp3',), daemon=True).start()
```

`daemon=True` here starts the thread as a daemon thread, meaning that it won't block the program from exiting. (On Python 2, you have do `t = threading.Thread(...); t.daemon = True; t.start()` instead.)