# How to use playsound Asynchronously?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-playsound

I know that if I do:

```
playsound("filepath.mp3", block=False)
```

that it is supposed to run asynchronously.

But when I try it, the mp3 file doesn't play, when I set it to `True` (default), the mp3 file plays -
but the program halts for the mp3 file to finish playing.

Also trying to run playsound on a different thread just results in an Error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play sound asynchronously in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042397/play-sound-asynchronously-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do play audio (playsound) in background of Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472162/how-do-play-audio-playsound-in-background-of-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is very late response but just do this:

```
playsound("filepath.mp3" , 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `execstring` in maXbox:

```
eng.Execstring('from playsound import playsound')
eng.Execstring('playsound(r"C:\Program Files\Streaming\maxbox4\maxbox4\airmaxloop3.mp3",0)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import playsound like this

```
import playsound
```

or

```
from playsound import playsound
```

Because i found that unless you import it from playsound it does not work

Comment: Yep, neither of them work, if i do True the sound is played but the program halts if i do False the sound is not played. Also it doesnt matter how i import it , if i do 
`import playsound` then i do `playsound.playsound("file.mp3", False)` for `from playsound import playsound` it is just `playsound("file.mp3",False)`. But still the problem persists