# how to handle multiple long-running user inputs with multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm working on a project where you pluck a different string(virtual string), and depending on where your finger is in space a sound is played. The problem is once you plug a string you cannot pluck another string until the sound is done playing. To combat this I wanted to set up threading to run each string as a separate function simultaneously. I'm not sure if this is how multithreading can be used. Here is the mock-up code I'm trying to get to work to then scale it and implement it into my actual code.

```
import threading, time, multiprocessing
a=1
b=2
c=3
def f1():
     val=input("enter 1")
     if val=='1':
         print("hello")
def f2():
     val=input("enter 2")
     if val=='2':
         print("hello b")
def f3():
     val=input("enter 3")
     if val=='3':
         print("hello c")

Thread1=threading.Thread(target=f1)
Thread2=threading.Thread(target=f2)
Thread3=threading.Thread(target=f3)
Thread1.start()
Thread2.start()
Thread3.start()
Thread1.join()
Thread2.join()
Thread3.join()
print("doneeeee")
```

The problem I'm having with this code is that it asks for the input but does not do the if statement; here is what I mean:

```
enter 11
enter 22
enter 33
doneeee
```

that is the terminal output.

Here is the actual function I'm trying to multithreaded.

```
def string1(): 
    if RT1<=R1:
        # bring the string to the finger--arduino
        if finger.is_extended:
            extended[0]=1
            print("pluck")
            # time.sleep(0.1)
        if not finger.is_extended and extended[0]==1:
            extended[0]=0            
            print(RT1) 
            print("String 1 has been plucked")
            playsound('/Desktop/soundG.mp3')
            # time.sleep(0.5)
            # quit()
            # make the sound play and move the string away-arduino
    else:
        print("whomp whomp whomp 1")
```

there is basically three of them just with the different initial condition.

Comment: The `input()` function always returns a string. Did you mean: `if val=='1':` etc?

Comment: that fixed it, still learning hahahha. I'm going to try it in my main code and let you know. Thank you though

Comment: so just tried it in my main code it's just executing the functions as normal so once the string is plucked it's still waiting for the sound to finish.

Comment: input is blocking - what is really happening (I think .... I'm not even totally sure how input works in threads) is that you have a race condition to determine which input call will actually receive your input. then, if that input line doesn't align with the "string" then nothing will happen. Instead, you should have a single "UI" thread listen for keystrokes then dispatch the sound output calls into threads. essentially you want a single app which is triggering async sound output in a "fire and forget" mode.

Comment: the problem is not at all how to get if statements inside threads. instead, think about what each thread is doing. only one of them can capture your input.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I think I understand what you are saying, so kind of like one thread for inputs and one for the sound, sorry if I completely butchered it. But here is the thing the input is from a leap motion camera so it's giving coordinates and those coordinates are used in a calculation which returns RT1, would this method still work with that?

Comment: You really, really, really don't want an `input()` inside a thread.  These should be in the main thread.

Comment: great question btw.

Comment: @codingnoob I think you got my message just fine! I don't understand the bit about a camera. but I think it just means this bit about having a single (main) thread parsing input is even more important.

Comment: I think you should check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043258/3888719

Comment: I just took a stab at clarifying your question title so others might find this question more easily - if you could take a look and make sure this fits your question that would be great :)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado yeah thank you the title is perfect now, and as for the answer, if I'm understanding it right, I think they are making the actual sound playing a thread, so for example in my code where it has the playsound function that is a thread. does that sound right

Comment: @FrankYellin is there a reason why or just rule of thumb

Comment: It's a good rule of thumb for keeping multi-threading code clean.  One thread is responsible for input, for for setting up the input.  It then passes it as an argument or via a queue to the workers.

Comment: it's not just a hygene issue though. think of your code like a physical piano. you have a reasonable request - you want the user to be able to play multiple notes at (nearly) the same time, with the sounds overlapping. in your implementation, you have done this by building multiple pianos, each of which only has one string. the user may only sit at one piano, and if they play a key not attached to a string, nothing happens. instead, build a single piano, with a "controller" (the keyboard) which triages the actions when a user plays the (single) interface and dispatches long-running tasks.

Comment: and yep @codingnoob that's exactly it

Comment: I'd give this a read to understand more about concurrency in python: https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/

Comment: @FrankYellin got it thanks, man. also that solution you sent me fixed my issue, which is also very similar to what you just sent me again. thank you

Comment: @MichaelDelgado hey man thank you for the solutions you gave me that first one you sent me solved it for me it is also basically the same as the second one from what I see, it kind of just fires a thread just to deal with the sound processing

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043258/3888719

```py
import threading

# not all of these are valid... but you get the idea
VALID_KEYS = [
    base+accent for base in "ABCDEFG" for accent in ["", "#", "b"]
]

def playsound(fp):
    """ dummy version of playsound demonstrating long function call"""
    import time
    print(f"playing sound {fp}")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"done playing sound {fp}")

def play_note(note):
    if note not in VALID_KEYS:
        raise KeyError(f"{note} not a valid note")

    fp = f'/Desktop/sound{note}.mp3'
    threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=(fp,), daemon=True).start()


def user_interface():
    while True:
        note = input("Enter a note to play: ")
        try:    
            play_note(note)
        except KeyError:
            print("that wasn't valid! exiting")
            break
```

This results in a UI which immediately handles the input and calls the sound, but does not wait for the sound to finish:

```
In [6]: user_interface()
Enter a note to play: A
playing sound /Desktop/soundA.mp3
Enter a note to play: Ab
playing sound /Desktop/soundAb.mp3
Enter a note to play: B#
playing sound /Desktop/soundB#.mp3
Enter a note to play: done playing sound /Desktop/soundA.mp3
ZZ
that wasn't valid! exiting

done playing sound /Desktop/soundAb.mp3
done playing sound /Desktop/soundB#.mp3
```

Comment: updated with bug fix & made the interface a bit more straightforward